# How to through error message in Yii2 Api?

Tags: api, error-handling, yii2, error-code

Here is the code attached.
How can I throw an error message if any attribute is missing?
I need to check if all attributes are coming from the form or not. If any attribute is missing I want to throw an error message with proper error code.

```
$get_email      = Null;
$get_password   = Null;
$get_username   = Null;

if (isset($_POST['username']) ) {
  $get_username = $_POST['username'];
}

if (isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['password']) ) {
  $get_email = $_POST['email'];
  $get_password = $_POST['password'];
}


if ($get_email == Null || $get_username == Null || $get_password == Null ) {
 // through error code with message
} 

else {
  $model = new SignupForm();
  $model->email   = $get_email; 
  $model->username = $get_username;
  $model->password = $get_password;
}
```

Comment: Did you even read something about handling user input in Yii2? Your code Is not Yii2 code, it's pure PHP.

Comment: Why don't you load attributes, apply validate() and then check $model->errors ? $model->attributes = $_POST; $model->validate();

Comment: This is extremely straight forward. If you added the code for the model you'll be able to get help much more easily

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code through which I have achieved my goal.

$model = new SignupForm;

```
if (isset($_POST['username'] )) {
    $model->username = $_POST['username'];
}

if (isset($_POST['email'] )) {
    $model->email = $_POST['email'];
}

if (isset($_POST['password'] )) {
    $model->password = $_POST['password'];
}

if($model->validate()){
    $model->signup();
}

else{
    return $model->getErrors();
}
```